# How to convert .tiff/.bmp to JPEG-XR with Imagemagick's convert tool?

Tags: imagemagick, image-compression, jpeg-xr

i'm using the `convert` tool from imagemagick to convert images to the jpeg-xr format.

i'm using the latest version under debian linux (ImageMagick-6.8.6-8).

The problem is `convert -format jxr` or `convert -format wdp` produce the same format as my source image and no valid jpeg-xr file.
Is my `-format` parameter wrong? i didn't find anything about it

thanks in advance

Comment: `JPEG extended range - Requires the jxrlib delegate library. Put the JxrDecApp and JxrEncApp applications in your execution path.` (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#supported) ..is this done already?

Comment: yes, this is done already.

Comment: Where did you find the JxrDecApp and JxrEncApp?

Comment: @Lucas The only place I found them online is here: https://github.com/4creators/jxrlib/tree/master/jxrencoderdecoder. I would also like to know where you put these files? What is considered the `execution path`? And do we need to rebuild imagemagick after doing this? I need to do this for macOS and Ubuntu 18. Does the `execution path` change for each OS?

Comment: did not see this question pop up but execution path refers to the PATH variable on your system it basically means that your OS can find those files when you want to execute them by itself. on linux you can either put the binarys in /usr/bin or anywhere on your system as long as you add the absolute folder path to your "PATH" variable. you can do this via your .bashrc or .zshrc or on windows with the "environment variable" menu. easy solution: for mac&linux chmod +x the files to make them executable and then put it in /usr/bin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-format` option is for outputting metadata in a specific format, not selecting the output file format.

Selecting a specific output format is done by prefixing the output filename with the tag described at http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php, so for example

```
convert input.jpg jxr:output.jpg
```

Normally, imagemagick detects the output format based on the file extension you chose for your output file, so by choosing `.jxr` as your file extension it should automatically use the JPEG-XR format.